# random image from getElementById not working with multiple filters

Tags: javascript, html

I have a large array named quotes with values and I am trying to display a random image from that query based on a filter on the artic section, with a new random image in each on button click. Right now, this is working for the randomIR, randomMR, and randomFR, but my other subsequent filters like randomIS are not

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("#btnSearch");

function GetValue() {
  var quotes = [{
        name: "Airplane",
        artic: ["medialR", "Rair", "medialP", "medialL", "finalN",
          img: "/img/airplane.png",
        },
        {
          name: "Ring",
          artic: ["initialR", "finalNG", "CVC", "syl1"],
          img: "/img/ring.png",
        },
        {
          name: "Soccer",
          artic: ["initialS", "medialK", "finalR", "Rer", "syl2"],
          img: "/img/soccer.png",
        },
        {
          name: "Gas",
          artic: ["initialG", "finalS", "CVC", "syl1"],
          img: "/img/emojibase/gas.png",
        },
        {
          name: "House",
          artic: ["syl1", "finalS", "CVC"],
          img: "/img/emojibase/house.png",
        }
      ];

      {
        const quotesIR = quotes.filter(x => x.artic.includes("initialR"));
        const quotesMR = quotes.filter(x => x.artic.includes("medialR"));
        const quotesFR = quotes.filter(x => x.artic.includes("finalR"));

        var randomIR = quotesIR[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesIR.length)];
        var randomMR = quotesMR[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesMR.length)];
        var randomFR = quotesFR[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesFR.length)];

        document.getElementById("IRtarget").src = randomIR.img;
        document.getElementById("MRtarget").src = randomMR.img;
        document.getElementById("FRtarget").src = randomFR.img;
      };

      {
        const quotesIS = quotes.filter(x => x.artic.includes("initialS"));
        const quotesMS = quotes.filter(x => x.artic.includes("medialS"));
        const quotesFS = quotes.filter(x => x.artic.includes("finalS"));

        var randomIS = quotesIS[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesIS.length)];
        var randomMS = quotesMS[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesMS.length)];
        var randomFS = quotesFS[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesFS.length)];

        document.getElementById("IStarget").src = randomIS.img;
        document.getElementById("MStarget").src = randomMS.img;
        document.getElementById("FStarget").src = randomFS.img;
      };

      btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        GetValue();
      });
```

```html
<div class="containerINITIAL" align="center">
  <br>
  <img id="IRtarget" src="/img/icons/rtest.png">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="containerMEDIAL" align="center">
    <br>
    <img id="MRtarget" src="/img/icons/rtest.png">
    <br>
    <button id="btnSearch" align="center" onclick="GetValue();">New Words</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="containerFINAL" align="center">
    <br>
    <img id="FRtarget" src="/img/icons/rtest.png">
  </div>

  <div class="containerINITIAL" align="center">
    <br>
    <img id="IStarget" src="/img/icons/stest.png">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="containerMEDIAL" align="center">
    <br>
    <img id="MStarget" src="/img/icons/stest.png">
    <br>
    <button id="btnSearch" align="center" onclick="GetValue();">New Words</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="containerFINAL" align="center">
    <br>
    <img id="FStarget" src="/img/icons/stest.png">
  </div>
```

Comment: Is this the full code you use? Why is there random `{` around the code?

Comment: No, this is not my full code, but the full thing has CSS and other related elements, so I just pulled out what was relevant to my question. I put the curly brackets around each section to make them easier to find in my code, they separate out each section

Answer (score 1):

It was erroring for me because there was no "medialS" entry. This occurs because the code is trying to index an entry in an empty array. For safety's sake, you should test the results of your filters before trying to use them. E.g.

```
const quotesIR = quotes.filter(x => x.artic.includes("initialR"));
if (quotesIR.length) {
    var randomIR = quotesIR[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesIR.length)];
    document.getElementById("IRtarget").src = randomIR.img;
}
```

I added a "medialS" entry to get the code working below, as well as a closing bracket after "finalN".

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("#btnSearch");

function GetValue() {
  var quotes = [{
          name: "Airplane",
          artic: ["medialR", "Rair", "medialP", "medialL", "finalN"],
          img: "/img/airplane.png",
        },
        {
          name: "Ring",
          artic: ["initialR", "finalNG", "CVC", "syl1"],
          img: "/img/ring.png",
        },
        {
          name: "Soccer",
          artic: ["initialS", "medialK", "finalR", "Rer", "syl2"],
          img: "/img/soccer.png",
        },
        {
          name: "Gas",
          artic: ["initialG", "finalS", "CVC", "syl1"],
          img: "/img/emojibase/gas.png",
        },
        {
          name: "House",
          artic: ["medialS","syl1", "finalS", "CVC"],
          img: "/img/emojibase/house.png",
        }
      ];

        const quotesIR = quotes.filter(x => x.artic.includes("initialR"));
        const quotesMR = quotes.filter(x => x.artic.includes("medialR"));
        const quotesFR = quotes.filter(x => x.artic.includes("finalR"));

        var randomIR = quotesIR[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesIR.length)];
        var randomMR = quotesMR[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesMR.length)];
        var randomFR = quotesFR[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesFR.length)];

        document.getElementById("IRtarget").src = randomIR.img;
        document.getElementById("MRtarget").src = randomMR.img;
        document.getElementById("FRtarget").src = randomFR.img;

        const quotesIS = quotes.filter(x => x.artic.includes("initialS"));
        const quotesMS = quotes.filter(x => x.artic.includes("medialS"));
        const quotesFS = quotes.filter(x => x.artic.includes("finalS"));

        var randomIS = quotesIS[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesIS.length)];
        var randomMS = quotesMS[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesMS.length)];
        var randomFS = quotesFS[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesFS.length)];

        document.getElementById("IStarget").src = randomIS.img;
        document.getElementById("MStarget").src = randomMS.img;
        document.getElementById("FStarget").src = randomFS.img;
      };
```

```html
<div class="containerINITIAL" align="center">
  <br>
  <img id="IRtarget" src="/img/icons/rtest.png">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="containerMEDIAL" align="center">
    <br>
    <img id="MRtarget" src="/img/icons/rtest.png">
    <br>
    <button id="btnSearch" align="center" onclick="GetValue();">New Words</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="containerFINAL" align="center">
    <br>
    <img id="FRtarget" src="/img/icons/rtest.png">
  </div>

  <div class="containerINITIAL" align="center">
    <br>
    <img id="IStarget" src="/img/icons/stest.png">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="containerMEDIAL" align="center">
    <br>
    <img id="MStarget" src="/img/icons/stest.png">
    <br>
    <button id="btnSearch" align="center" onclick="GetValue();">New Words</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="containerFINAL" align="center">
    <br>
    <img id="FStarget" src="/img/icons/stest.png">
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi there! Thank you so much for your input. My full array has 800+ entries and has intitial/medial/final values for everything. I put "house" as medialS even though it was wrong to try not to give too much unnecessary info. Your code works great as-is, but when I remove the R targets, it no longer runs. I only want the initial/medial/final of one consonant sound per page. Any advice?

Comment: I stripped down the HTML you sent and put it into a table instead of columns (the alignment was giving me issues) and I've put them up on my site so you can see what I mean:

Comment: http://languageplayroom.com/articulation/sr-imf-basketball.html
http://languageplayroom.com/articulation/s-imf-basketball.html
http://languageplayroom.com/articulation/r-imf-basketball.html

You can see how it runs fine when there are R images but not when there are S, and both are in the javascript as you wrote them.

Answer (score 0):

From your notes and links, it looks like there's a different problem. When you have no 'R' images, you are getting an error because your function is still trying to set them. For example, `document.getElementById("IRtarget")` will return `null` on that page which causes an error when you try to set it's `src` property.

You could test for those elements before trying to set them:

```
if (document.getElementById("IRtarget")) {
    const quotesIR = quotes.filter(x => x.artic.includes("initialR"));
    var randomIR = quotesIR[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesIR.length)];
    document.getElementById("IRtarget").src = randomIR.img;
}
```

Comment: Did that solve your problem or are you still having issues?